# Does Dart have any log manager which can put logs in files (email etc.)?

Tags: file, logging, dart

I mean is the logger similar to log4j?

I found these loggers:

```
https://pub.dev/packages/logger;
https://pub.dev/packages/simple_logger;
https://pub.dev/packages/quick_log;
```

but they can't write in a file.

`https://pub.dev/packages/f_logs`
can't send email

`https://pub.dev/packages/log_4_dart_2`
do not work for me

Answer (score 1):

[Logger Readme](https://pub.dev/packages/logger)

If you had read documentation, they have already provided solution where you can extend default logger to do anything with output.

Simply extend output class and send it to email or write through file streams or even log it to database, choice is yours.

```
class ConsoleOutput extends LogOutput {
    @override void output(OutputEvent event) {
        for (var line in event.lines) {
            print(line); 
        }
}
```

You can write file and then get its contents via email service to do your reporting task.